# Cant loop through a array of images in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[Here is my array from the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBgCZ.jpg)

[and my code to fetch the array and pass it to a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx90D.jpg)

### 1- productDetails object

```
{
    "data": {
        "product_id": 661,
        "quantity": 1,
        "category_id": 107,
        "sub_category_id": 110,
        "product_name": "Top Quality Concise Crystal Ring",
        "product_description": "Top Quality Concise Crystal Ring\r\nRing Size 5.5 Main \r\nStone Color: Clear \r\nMetal Color: Rose Gold",
        "variations": [],
        "product_price": "100.00",
        "product_discount_percent": 0,
        "product_discount_price": "100.00",
        "shop_phone_no": "9504874",
        "shop_delivery_location": "Male",
        "liked_users_count": 1,
        "total_related_products_count": 4,
        "liked_users": [
            {
                "following_user_id": 2915,
                "full_name": "Muna Adam",
                "profile_photo": "https://aiminaabee.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/users/profile/1867235433581879",
                "total_liked_products": 15,
                "follow": 0
            }
        ],
        "product_images": [
            "https://aiminaabee.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/testing/products/Aiminaabee%20Shop/jdvPxcPp573DrxkBtMY9vlOuCwAWyilE4Tvg9XAJ.jpeg",
            "https://aiminaabee.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/testing/products/Aiminaabee%20Shop/CQ9vmKNi8wENHNBRZOOv3Dl3n2MutdTOIXyZ2lKs.jpeg",
            "https://aiminaabee.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/testing/products/Aiminaabee%20Shop/LVbWDx7my8u9kArn7zBSDHTZKt5khyfmal0ZlE18.jpeg"
        ],
        "liked_status": 0,
        "is_incart": "0"
    },
    "message": "Product detail found.",
    "status": 1 }
```

This is the component inside i am trying to fetch data

```
    render(){

    const { productDetails, RelatedDetails } = this.props;

    return (

        <ScrollView>

            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.productImage}>
                --------------------------------------------
                 <Swiper
                    showsPagination={true}
                    height={348}>
                    {productDetails.product_images.map(img => (
                        <ImageCard
                            img={img}
                        />
                    ))}
                 </Swiper>
               ----------------------------------------------

                </View>
                <LikeControls 
                    likedStatus={productDetails.liked_status}
                />
                <View style={styles.ProductInfor}>
                    <Text> MVR: {productDetails.product_price} </Text>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._prodInfoHndler}>
                        <Text style={{color:'#1DA1F2'}}> Product Information </Text>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>

                <SellerDetails 
                    shopPhone={productDetails.shop_phone_no}
                    delvLoc={productDetails.shop_delivery_location}
                />
                <View style={styles.AddToCartButton}>
                    <DefaultButton
                        bgColor ="#1B95E0"
                        margin  = {0}
                        radius  = {50}
                        padding = {10}
                        width   = {250}
                        onPress={this.emailSignInHandler}
                        >
                        Add To Cart
                    </DefaultButton>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.heading}>
                    <Text> Related Items </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.relatedItems}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={func.formatData(RelatedDetails,constants.COLUMS)}
                        numColumns={constants.COLUMS}
                        //onEndReached={this._fetchResult}
                        //onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        ListFooterComponent={() => <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}><ProgressBar /></View>}
                        renderItem={(info)=>(
                            <ProductGrid
                                data={info.item}
                                showProduct={this._productRelatedSelectedHandler}
                                />
                        )}
                        />
                </View>
            </View>

        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

The error says cant read property of map undefined from the emulator.

1- ProductDetails is an object
2- Product_images is an array inside ProductDetails object. 
3- Trying to loop through all the images inside Product_images and pass it to a component names ImageCard as props.

This is the ImageCard Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, View } from 'react-native';


const ImageCard = props => {

    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
          <Image
              style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}
              source={{uri: props.img }}
            />
      </View>
    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex:1
  }
})

export default ImageCard
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. Are you receiving any console errors? What does your `<Swiper />` component look like? I assume it is the `react-native-swiper` module?

Comment: The error says cant read property of map undefined from the emulator. The problem here is i'm not be in able to loop through elements in the array. is the right way to loop through? when i console log the i'm getting the array with image links. not sure what' wrong?

Comment: This should work. Could you provide a repo so that I can attempt to reproduce?

Comment: Yes. its react-native-swiper module. the idea here is to fetch images from api and include them in the swiper. inside the swiper im looping through images and sending information to ImageCard component as props. ImageCard component is just functional component with image formatting. eg. width height etc...

Comment: Your problem could be the '100%' height and width. If your parent elements don't have a static height and width, this wouldn't render. Have you tried setting these statically?

Comment: Yes. But as the error says "cant read property of map undefined" is it a problem of dimentions in the image problem? I have also update the question

Comment: Thanks for the update! Odd situation, but try accessing the images like so: `productDetails['product_images'].map` instead of `productDetails.product_images.map`

Comment: I think its the same error. tried may few different debugs. also console loged the array from the same component witch im trying to fetch. the data is right there

Comment: That's what I expected, but asked just in case. Could you create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can debug this for you? Or a public repo if that's easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) say:

`Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!`

`<ImageCard
     img={img}
     style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
  />`

Anyway, as NorianNyx more information may be needed in order to give the right answer.

Comment: This is likely the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i couldnt get it working through props. So this is what i did.
1- called the action
2- got results
3- put into state array
4- took it from the state.array and looped using map function. it worked.

Here is my code.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
    images: [],
    likedUsers: []
 };

 this._productRelatedSelectedHandler = 
 this._productRelatedSelectedHandler.bind(this);

}
------------------------------------
componentWillMount() {
    this._retrieveProductDetails();
}

_retrieveProductDetails() {
    this.props.actions.ProductDetail(this.props.pid)
        .then(() => {

            this._retrieveRelatedInformations ( 
                this.props.productDetails.category_id, 
                this.props.productDetails.sub_category_id 
            );

            this.setState({
                images: this.props.productDetails.product_images,
                likedUsers: this.props.productDetails.liked_users,
            });

        });
}
-------------------------------------
_getLikedUsers = () => {

    if((this.state.likedUsers).length > 0 ){
        return (
            <View style={styles.ProductLikedUsers}>   
                {this.state.likedUsers.map(img => (
                    <LikedUsers
                        img={img.profile_photo}
                        user_id={img.following_user_id}
                    />
                ))}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just avoid that `"` in the `product_images` initialization.

Change:

```
"product_images": [....]
```

to:

```
product_images: [....]
```

Comment: "product_images" to product_images:[•••]

Comment: don't add to your answer in comments, [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51214304/edit)

Comment: This shouldn't matter. Object keys can be either quoted or unquoted as long as they are valid identifiers. If not valid identifiers, they must be quoted in strict mode.